# Is there a way to overload every possible function on a class?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, transpiler

I am trying to implement a reference - like class called Ref. Currently, the class contains a pointer to my object. The class should behave like a natural object.
The skeleton of the class looks like this:

```
template typename<T>

class Ref {
public:
    T* value;
    // Constructors - not really important

}
```

I would like that the user could use the class as follows:

```
void foo(int x) {// whatever is there doesn't really matter}
int main() {
       auto x = Ref<int>(5) // Hopefully with c++20 the user would just write Ref(5)
       foo(x); // Should be converted to foo(*(x.value))
       x += 5; // Should be converted to *(x.value) += 5
}
```

The pattern here is that any function foo applied to a Ref object would be converted to foo(*(x.value)). How can this be done?? Therefore, the user would be able to use a Ref object just like a normal object.

I know one possible solution:

```
template typename<T>

class Ref {
public:
    T* value;
    template <typename R> 
    R apply(R (*foo) (ref<T>)) {return foo(*value);}

}
```

However, now the user has to type

```
auto x = Ref<int>(5);
x.apply(foo);
```

Which I don't want at all; I want my Ref object to behave like a natural object.

Why don't I use references instead : I want to be able to make an array of Ref objects.
Why don't I use pointers instead: I want to add additional constraints to the Ref class to make it safer than pointers.

This is not the only use case I can think of, another case where overloading every possible function is desirable is when you want to implement an array of objects of type T class which behaves like this:

```
void foo(int x) {///Whatever is here}
int main()
{
   auto y = CustomArray<int>{1,2,3,4};
   foo(y); // applies foo to every element of y (element - wise) 
}
```

Note : I am aware that this is probably very difficult / impossible to do in pure c++. However, I am open to some solutions which take in a file where the writer writes foo(x) (x is a Ref object here) and which converts this to a c++ file in which you have x.apply(foo); (like a sort of transpiler).

Comment: Do you want to reimplement [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)?

Comment: Looks like you want a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Comment: Additionally, the `Ref(5);` syntax is available in `c++17` with [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Comment: @super Yes that looks like exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much.